# Set time with moment .js on node.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am trying to format time the time I am sending with moment.js.   I am using the multiple locale support  **moment().format('L');    // 06/04/2015**

I have installed moment with the node package module **"moment": "^2.10.3",**

I made sure to require it in my app.js var moment = require ('moment') and on my router.js file;  Here is my post request.  This is where I assume I would make the time change.  However, I get an error about my post when I try it.

```
router.post('/drinks',function(req,res,next){

console.log(req.body);
var formData = req.body;
var newDrink = new Drink({
    name: formData.name,
    date: formData.moment(data).format('L'),
    caffeineLevel: formData.caffeineLevel
});

newDrink.save(function(err,result){
    if(err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.send(result);
});
```

});

Also, here is my mongo model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var drinkSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    date: {
        type:Date,
        default: new Date()
    },
    caffeineLevel: String

});

var Drink = mongoose.model('Drink',drinkSchema);

module.exports = Drink;
```

I thought I might use it in the model, but I could not figure out how it would work.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please give the answer or accept a given answer. If not, update your post with more information :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are not parsing your form data as a date, you are formating the current date with the 'L' format.

Try that instead (assuming your date input is named date) :

```
var newDrink = new Drink({
  name: formData.name,
  date: moment(formData.data).toDate(),
  caffeineLevel: formData.caffeineLevel
});
```